# mv brace expansion with globbing in script

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I'm trying to move photos to a different directory.  It works great when I run `mv` from the command line (in bash and zsh):

```
mv './DSC_{2385..2387}.NEF*' ./new/STACK_2385-2387
```

I wrote this bash script that moves a series of photos to a different directory.

But not if I run it from a script:

```
#/bin/bash
set -x
read START
read END
PREFIX="STACK"
DIRNAME=$PREFIX\_$START-$END
mkdir ./new/$DIRNAME
mv ./DSC_{$START..$END}.NEF* ./new/$DIRNAME
```

.

```
$./script.sh
mv ./DSC_{$START..$END}.NEF* ./new/$DIRNAME
+ mkdir ./new/STACK_2385-2387
+ mv './DSC_{2385..2387}.NEF*' ./new/STACK_2385-2387
mv: cannot stat './DSC_{2385..2387}.NEF*': No such file or directory
```

`./new/STACK_2385-2387` is being created. The relevant `*.NEF` raws and `*.NEF.xmp` sidecar files also exist, including 2385, 2386, *and* 2387, so it's not an issue there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with interactive versus non-interactive, but with trying to use parameters in the brace expansion. Brace expansion happens before all other expansions, so you can't do that.

Comment: Where are you setting `START` and `END`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks I didn't know that. See karakfa's answer for a workaround. Good catch with `START` and `END`; I've adjusted the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only do variable brace expansion with evil `eval` as in this example

```
$ a=1; b=10; eval echo {$a..$b}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

so you need to change `mv` command to

```
$ eval mv ./DSC_{$START..$END}.NEF* ./new/"$DIRNAME"
```

perhaps double quote the variables as well.